# If $\|B\|<1/\|A^{-1}\|$ then $A+B\in\mathcal L{\rm is}(E,F)$

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

Reading the book *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher I find the following assertion in page 214:

> Let $A\in\mathcal L{\rm is}(E,F)$ and $B\in\mathcal L(E,F)$. Then according to $\rm (i)$ if $\|B\|<1/\|A^{-1}\|$ then $A+B\in\mathcal L{\rm is}(E,F)$.

Here $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. The set $\mathcal L{\rm is}(E,F)$ is the set of topological isomorphisms between $E$ and $F$.

In $\rm (i)$ it was proved that $\mathcal L{\rm is}(E,F)$ is open in $\mathcal L(E,F)$:

> [image: img]

and

> [image: img2]

where $\mathcal L{\rm aut}(E)$ is the set of topological automorphisms of $E$.

From all of this I dont follow the assertion that open this question, at most what I can says is that $\|A+B\|\le\|A\|+\|B\|\le \|A\|+1/\|A^{-1}\|$, but I dont see how this is related to $\rm (i)$, that is, why $A+B$ is invertible.

Can someone enlighten me please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible $A+B = A(I + A^{-1}B)$, also it follows from the assumptions on $B$ that $||A^{-1}B||\leq ||A^{-1}||\ ||B||< \frac {||A^{-1}||} {||A^{-1}||} = 1$. So by the lemma you cite $(I+ A^{-1}B)$ is invertible and since the composition of invertible is  invertible $ A(I + A^{-1}B)=A+B$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice.